# Excel Cross Reference Using LOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been given a task, in which I must go through a thousand entries on two excel sheets and copy over one value. They are not in the same order, so I have to manually search for each entry. I decided to try to make a function for this.

```
=LOOKUP(C113,'[RoleTree_2016-6-29]Sheet2'!E$2:E$2687,'[RoleTree_2016-6-29]Sheet2'!A$2:A$2687)
```

This function does not work properly, and I have no clue why. I am attempting to copy the A column variable where the E variable equals the target documents C variable. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Index](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)/[Match](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) instead:

```
=INDEX('[RoleTree_2016-6-29]Sheet2'!A$2:A$2687,Match(C113,'[RoleTree_2016-6-29]Sheet2'!E$2:E$2687,0))
```